# dmesg -c: read kernel buffer failed, operation not permitted

Tags: kernel, dmesg

I am working with kernel modules and therefore I need to work over dmesg outputs. However, I can not command **dmesg -c**. I can dmesg, yet can't clear the buffer. I searched for solutions such as

> sudo sysctl kernel.dmesg_restrict =0

Yet they do not solve the problem. Why can't I clear the buffer?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in [`man 2 syslog`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syslog.2.html#DESCRIPTION): all syslog commands except for “read all” and “size” are available only to root. `dmesg_restrict` only controls access to “read all” and “size”; setting it to 1 restricts them to root, setting it to 0 makes them available to non-root processes.

`dmesg -c` requires root (strictly speaking, `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` or `CAP_SYSLOG`) in all cases:

```
sudo dmesg -c
```

Comment: Thank you but I did not understand well. So, in my view, passing 0 should allow me to clear the dmesg?

Comment: No, passing 0 only enables the `dmesg` commands that read all the buffer. It doesn’t enable any other command, including `dmesg -c`; those commands are always privileged, `dmesg_restrict` doesn’t affect them.

Comment: I understand now. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Also, if there is an answer in your words, I can't see it. I just started to study Linux and before that, I always use dmesg -c with no problem, without any pre-permission.

Comment: So you’re saying you used to able to run `dmesg -c` without being root?

Comment: Yes. I do not know why people downvoted me lol.

Answer (score 0):

Just go with the `sudo dmesg -c` guys. I already knew it works but I wondered why it stopped working without `sudo`. However, no satisfying answer, then I choose to go with safer one.